# Synonymous struct field and method name for interface

Tags: go, struct, interface

I'm building a type structure that represents some devices on my network. There are lots of types of these devices, such as:

```
type Foo struct  { ... }
type Bar struct  { ... }
type Spam struct { ... }
```

but they all share a few common fields, one of which is `IP`. I'd like to define `Device` as an interface so I can group these together logically

```
type Device interface {
    IP() string
    ...
}

type LogicalGrouping struct {
    Devices []Device
    ...
}
```

but I'm running into an error with overlapping names.

```
func (f *Foo) IP() string { return f.IP }  // same method name as field name
```

I can rename either the field or the method or both, but surely this must be a common use case -- grouping structs by the fields they have in common? Is there an idiomatic solution here?

Comment: The usual solution here is to rename your struct fields so they are unexported.

Comment: You can't have a field and a method with the same name. What you want to name your fields and methods, so long as they are syntactically valid, is entirely up to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interface naming convention Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842457/interface-naming-convention-golang)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is that interfaces define behaviours and fields define data.

The problem here is that you are using an interface to access data in fields. On it's own that's not necessarily a bad thing. But you might want to reconsider how to structure your code so that you don't get this collision.

**The first question I would as is:**

"Why do you need to export the field `IP` if the `struct` defines an `IP()` method that has access to it?"

You could make the struct field unexported i.e. `ip` not `IP`, and then in the place you are using `struct.IP`, use `struct.IP()` instead.

**The second question is:**

"If you have structs such as `foo`, `bar`, `spam` and they all share common fields, why not use composition to deduplicate the definition of those shared fields."

*This would probably only work if you are really only after the data that's inside the struct, I would generally advocate for using interfaces in all cases.*

If you have the following structs:

```
type Foo struct {
    IP string
    A string 
    B string
}

type Bar struct {
    IP string
    A string 
    B string
}

type Spam struct {
    IP string
    A string 
    B string
}
```

You could use a new struct to represent the fields they have in common, and anonymously compose that inside:

```
type Inner struct {
    IP string
    A string 
    B string
}

type Foo struct {
    Inner
}

type Bar struct {
    Inner
}

type Spam struct {
    Inner
}
```

In the function call where you were using `struct.IP()`, accept an `Inner` and call it with `struct.Inner`. You will still have access to `struct.IP` even though `IP` is defined inside `Inner`.

Comment: the former method (`foo.ip` unexported, using `foo.IP()` for data access) is what I ended up using. My brain doesn't twist that way naturally, as I more readily consider `func (f *foo) IP() string` to be a method on the interface, not a method on the struct -- which is nonsense of course.

Answer (score 0):

You also may consider option to have `ip` field and `GetIP` & `SetIP` methods (or `IP` & `SetIP` accordingly to this [doc](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters)) - it's clear, concise and simple.

Comment: In general in go you would not create `GetFoo()` methods, instead opting for the simpler form of just `Foo()`.  https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters

Comment: @Zak Updated my answer. Thank you!