# r and w in ResponseWriter and Request Golang

Tags: go

This is a bit a silly question but I wanted to ask that can I use any name instead of `r` and `w` in the `w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request` or should it be `r` and `w` always?

Thanks

Comment: You can use any parameter name. You can even omit or discard the parameter name. Only the function's/method's parameter types matter when you are trying to implement a specific func type or interface.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your response. I am fairly new to Golang.Can you help me with tutorials to better objects and pointers in function in Golang?

Comment: The official [Go website](https://go.dev/doc/) has lot of well written and easily digestible content. The most relevant being the [language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec). Outside of the official stuff I'm aware only of Dave Cheney's [blog](https://dave.cheney.net/) being consistently solid.

Comment: Naming of variables in Go is obviously not governed by the language specification (except for a well-known Go's hallmark using of capitalization of the 1st letters of identifiers to make them exported from the package); it's rather a question of style and best practices. Hence such stuff is not explicitly codified. Still, there are good "alost official" guidelines: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments and https://go.dev/blog/package-names and https://go.dev/blog/organizing-go-code (old, but everything about names still 100% holds).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482068/

Comment: Also here on SO [@icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza) has by far the most comprehensive answers under the Go tag. If you're interested in a specific topic, try searching through his answers and you just may find what you are looking for. For example: ["pointer"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a1705598%20pointer)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter the name of the parameter, you just need to obey the function signature

```
func (firstParameter http.ResponseWriter, secondParameter http.ResponseWriter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you asking is, is it idomatic to use `r` and `w`. I don’t think it is. So long as you give the parameters reasonable names (i.e. they don’t hinder readability) you are fine.